# Не обновляется таблица

Tags: php, javascript

Есть скрипт, который обновляет таблицу с ордерами на сайте каждые 3 секунды, но когда в таблице остается один ордер и его скупают, то таблица перестает обновляться и ордер не пропадает, информацию о ордерах скрипт берет из БД

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").bind("click", function() {

        var price = $('.priceField').val();
        var amount = $('.amountField').val();
        var total = $('.totalField').val();

        $('.priceField').val('');
        $('.amountField').val('');
        $('.totalField').val('');

        $.ajax({
            url: "for_db.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {price:price, amount:amount, total: total}, // Передаем данные для записи
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                if (result){ 
                    $('.rows tr').remove();
                    $('.rows').append(function(){
                        var res = '';
                        for(var i = 0; i < result.ordersbuy.total.length; i++){
                            res += '<tr><td>' + result.ordersbuy.id[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.price[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.amount[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.total[i] + '</td></tr>';
                        }
                            return res;
                    });
                    console.log(result);
                }else{
                    alert(result.message);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    return false;
    });


//Через каждые 3 секунды посылаем аякс запрос    
 setInterval(function(){ 
 $.ajax({
            url: "for_db.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {refresh:true}, // Передаем данные для записи
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
            if (result){ 
                $('.orders__table').html(function(){
                    var res = '';
                    for(var i = 0; i < result.ordersbuy.ordtime.length; i++){
            var OrdTime = new Date(result.ordersbuy.ordtime[i]*1000);
            OrdYear=addZero(OrdTime.getFullYear());
            OrdMonth=addZero(OrdTime.getMonth()+1);
            OrdDay=addZero(OrdTime.getDate());
            OrdHour=addZero(OrdTime.getHours());
            OrdMin=addZero(OrdTime.getMinutes());
            OrdSec=addZero(OrdTime.getSeconds());
            if (result.ordersbuy.Type[i]=='BUY'){
                res += '<div class="orders__table-row" onclick='+'Trade("Orders_Row_'+i+'"); id="Orders_Row_'+i+'">' +
                '<div class="orders__table-pair">' + result.ordersbuy.Prod[i] + '/' + result.ordersbuy.Val[i] + '</div>' + 
                '<div class="orders__table-buy">' +result.ordersbuy.Type[i]+ '</div>' + 
                '<div class="orders__table-amount">' + result.ordersbuy.amount[i]/100000000 + '</div>' +
                '<div class="orders__table-price">' + result.ordersbuy.price[i] + '</div>' + 
                '<div class="orders__table-time">' +OrdYear+'.'+OrdMonth+'.'+OrdDay+' '+OrdHour+':'+OrdMin+':'+OrdSec+ '</div>' + 
                '<div class="orders__table-status">'+ "OPEN"+ '</div>' + 
                '<div class="orders__table-close"><img src="img/icons/orders__close.png"></div>' +
                '</div>';
            }
            if (result.ordersbuy.Type[i]=='SELL'){
                res += '<div class="orders__table-row" onclick='+'Trade("Orders_Row_'+i+'"); id="Orders_Row_'+i+'">' +
                '<div class="orders__table-pair">' + result.ordersbuy.Prod[i] + '/' + result.ordersbuy.Val[i] + '</div>' + 
                '<div class="orders__table-buy orders__table-buy--sell">' +result.ordersbuy.Type[i]+ '</div>' + 
                '<div class="orders__table-amount">' + result.ordersbuy.amount[i]/100000000 + '</div>' +
                '<div class="orders__table-price">' + result.ordersbuy.price[i] + '</div>' + 
                '<div class="orders__table-time">' +OrdYear+'.'+OrdMonth+'.'+OrdDay+' '+OrdHour+':'+OrdMin+':'+OrdSec+ '</div>' +  
                '<div class="orders__table-status">'+ "OPEN"+ '</div>' + 
                '<div class="orders__table-close"><img src="img/icons/orders__close.png"></div>' +
                '</div>';
            }
        }
        return res;
    });
    console.log(result);
            } 
            else {
                $('.orders__table').html(function(){
                    var res = '';
                    return res;
                });
            }
                return false;
            }
        });
 }, 1000);   

});
```

Comment: `if (result)` то вы обновляете данные. На самом деле их нужно обновлять всегда. Просто когда нет данных, вы должны обнулять содержимое `$('.orders__table')`

Comment: а где скрипт работы с базой? приведите код вашего php-файла.